# Why MATLAB's optical flow (LK) is very fast compare to original method?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm referring to the function [opticalflowlk](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/opticalflowlk-class.html) in MATLAB. If you try out with a 4K image of size `A=rand(3648,5472)`, the built-in function compute in a matter of seconds. However if I try to re-implement the method from the theory, it took very long time. Any idea what kind of computation method MATLAB used? Below is the code of my implementation.

```
ImRef=rand(3648,5472);
ImNext=rand(3648,5472);
[Ix, Iy]=gradient(ImRef);
[Ix2, Iy2]=gradient(ImNext);
It = conv2(ImRef, 0.25*ones(2),'same') + conv2(ImNext, -0.25*ones(2),'same');

ww = 45;
w = round(ww/2);

u = zeros(size(Ix));
v = zeros(size(Ix));


for i = w+1:size(Ix,1)-w
    for j = w+1:size(Ix,2)-w
        Ixw = Ix(i-w:i+w, j-w:j+w);
        Iyw = Iy(i-w:i+w, j-w:j+w);
        Itw = It(i-w:i+w, j-w:j+w);

        X = [Ixw(:)  Iyw(:)];
        B=regress(-Itw(:), X);

        u(i,j)=B(1);
        v(i,j)=B(2);
    end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

I suspect MATLAB's is not the 'dense' as it should. Since it only detect edges movement after few experiments. Please correct me if I'm wrong.